# I want to output the number that contain "7" as the LUCKY NUMBER and the number that can be divided evenly by 7 as LUCKY NUMBER

Tags: javascript

I tried this code. It works for number that can be divided evenly by 7 as Lucky Numbers. But it doesn't work for some numbers. I can't find where I made a mistake.

```
for(i=1; i<=1000; i++)
{
    var x = 7;
    var y = i;
    var z = y % x ;
    if ( z == 0  )
    {

        document.write("Lucky Number" +"<br>");
        i++;
    }

    var number = i; 
    var num = number.toString();
    var matchedposition = num.search(["7"]);

    if ( matchedposition == true )
    {

        document.write("Lucky Number" +"<br>");
        i++;
    }
    document.write(i+"<br>");
}
```

Comment: Why are you incrementing your loop variable inside the for loop as well as in the for syntax?

Comment: Like @SatejS said. Also, your use of the `search` function looks wrong.

Comment: Your search logic is definitely wrong. I've attached a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y8pL4kzf/) for the answer below and your [answer](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb2nLueo/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
for(i=1; i<=1000; i++)
{

    var z = i % 7 ;
    if (( z == 0  ) &&( i.toString().search(7)))
    {
        console.log("Lucky Number"+ i +"<br>");
    }
}
```

So here in this code i did two things

1)  I am not incrementing 'i' after every If . Because if you increment i after every IF condition then you will not check all numbers from 1 to 1000 . So whenever yours condition will be true u increase i by one and then again i will increment by loop. so you are escaping one number to be checked.

2)  I combine both condition together to reduce code.

I hope it will help you

Comment: 1) You don't need to define `x=7` inside the loop. 2) You don't need `y`, just use `i`. 3) You don't need `==true`

Answer (score -1):

Try this not sure:

```
  for(i=1; i<=1000; i++)
                {
                    var x = 7;
                    var y = i;
                    var z = y % x ;
                    var isFound=false;
                    if ( z == 0  )
                    {

                        document.write("Lucky Number" +"<br>");
                         isFound =true;

                    }

                    var number = i; 
                    var num = number.toString();
                    var matchedposition = num.search("7");

                     if ( matchedposition > 0 && !isFound)
                    {

                        document.write("Lucky Number" +"<br>");

                    }
                    document.write(i+"<br>");

                }
```

Comment: Are you sure he should be incrementing i in the loop?

Comment: @SatejS yes no need to increament as for loop has i++ so updated my answer. thanks

Comment: His/Her search logic seems wrong, which renders your answer incorrect. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y8pL4kzf/)